# google play console ads permission in manifest file problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest, ads, ironsource

Recently, I integrated IronSource ads sdk into my unity game and after building and uploading to google play console, a warning occured: "Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.".

I turned on custom main manifest option in unity editor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnL8S.png)

And added this line to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

Final AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />   
    
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As a result, after re-uploading the build, I again get the same error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUUp6.png)
What could be the reason for the repeated error?

I tried the following:

1. building without custom manifest
2. building with custom manifest and adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

tag
3. adding the same tag at the end of manifest, before manifest and after application closing tags.
4. exporting unity game, to then import it to android studio and build from there using custom manifests with the same ad permission tag as well.
5. tried using different ad permission tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
```

nothing helped

(p.s. I also built the game as an .apk file and the test ads worked fine. It probably means that ad permission worked properly, and the problem was in google play console services, or other stuff like that)

[and in the app bundle explorer my app does have this permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jKV3.png)

Comment: This also happened with me, and for me the solution was to remove all any of the previous builds that is in any of the tack ie. Internal Testing, Close Testing, etc...